# Match string only if not followed by another specific string

Tags: php, regex

I have `#[\s]+on[a-z]+[\s]*=#si`. I need to match (**preg_replace**) string like `onclick =` but only if this string isn't followed by another specific string.

Example (bold is the match)

> some text **onClickOrWhatever =** some text
>
> some text onClickOrWhatever = my special string some text

Second line shouldn't be matched because the expression is follow by "my special string". In another words, I need to keep intact specific inline javascript but remove(destroy) any other.

*This expression is a little too general. It would also partially match `you told me once =)`, I am aware of that.*

Comment: You're doing this backwards. You can't have `some text` AND `my special string` as both being special, something to look for. You can find the special, leave it alone, or destroy it. Maybe you can word it better.

Comment: Also, you won't be able to remove what you don't match. Even after a lookahead, still need to match something, unless you just going to rename the attribute.

Comment: @sln I'm not sure what do you mean. Accepted answer with lookahead works just fine. I only need to remove(replace) `onEVENT=` as long as it isn't followed by something specific. See this [link](http://rubular.com/r/mMnlHUnQ08)

Comment: You lost me. But you never gave examples in a larger sense, so nobody knows if you're replacing JS code or whatever. The main point might be that Not my special string, never becomes part of the match, to be replaced or whatever. JS shouldn't really be parsed with regex anyway.

Comment: @sln "my special string" doesn't need to be part of the match, I don't need that replaced. I know, I should rather parse DOM the proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to answer your question, you can use `negative lookahead`:

```
#\s+on[a-z]+\s*=(?!\s*my special string)#i
```

You also don't need `s` flag here which is used for making `DOT` match `newline`.

Comment: Any special reason why equal sign has been moved to the end? Anyway thanks, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Saix: NO special reason, that was a typo, let me fix it.

Comment: It also works if there is another string between `onclick=` and `my special string`. Could it be modified the way, it would only lookahead right after? not search the whole text...